# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED error with node.js local host

Tags: node.js, networking, server

I am trying to run an application on localhost but keep receiving this error when I try to run it. What is wrong? On one of my computers, this works but on one it does notwork.

```
 at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
 at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
```

Comment: Did you checked the port you are running it?

Comment: Can you provide your server code? and how did you connect to it?

Comment: How do I Check the port. It say port 80 and 3000. what is a server code? I did cmd: node index and enter.